# Ubuntu 16.04 update-grub doesn't update grub.cfg but menu.lst

Tags: 16.04, grub2, grub-legacy

After being stuck on kernel 4.4.0-22 for some time, I manually upgraded today, but found out that update-grub does not update my grub.cfg file, but my menu.lst file. After manually running grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg, it was updated and I had the new kernel. This made me a bit suspicious and I checked my grub version:

```
Ii grub 0.97-29ubuntu68 amd64 GRand Unified Bootloader (Legacy version)
Ii grub-common 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.7 amd64GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)
Rc grub-legacy-ec2 0.7.7~bzr1212-0ubuntu1 all Handles update-grub for ec2 instances
Rc grub-pc 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3 amd64 GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)
```

It seems it still uses grub and not grub2 for some reason. I am also able to install grub2-common from the packet manager. Now, how do I fix it so that is uses the correct update command? Do I just install grub2-common? I ask this, because I am not entirely sure and don't want to mess up my installation. I can not access the machine physically for at least another month. In the end, I would like to switch to the HWE track to have a more current kernel, but for that I want to make sure that update-grub works.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

purge old and reinstall new to sda

```
sudo apt-get purge grub grub-pc grub-common
sudo mv /boot/grub /boot/grub_backup
sudo mkdir /boot/grub
sudo apt-get install grub-pc grub-common
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid reinstalling it completely. Mainly, if something goes wrong, I have no way of fixing it currently. Might there be complications if I have the system on one drive and /home on another drive that has a software raid? It looks to me that it might cause a problem when I completely remove the bootloader and reinstall it, including reconfiguration.

Comment: That only reinstalls grub2, but you always need a full system backup and a working live installer or repair disk with any system whether Ubuntu or Windows. Hard drives fail, lightning strikes, power failures, user errors all can cause system corruption and then you need a way to fix or restore system. If you have RAID on, but different partitions on different drives, you really cannot have RAID on. RAID has to see exactly same partition structure on both drives. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Then it should work remotely. Although I will probably still try it only when I have physical access. I am aware that a backup is useful, anything can fail. Regarding the RAID, I have my system on a SSD, but the /home folder is on two HDDs, where there is a software RAID 1. So only my data is on the RAID drives. For now that works perfectly. I can not pose the Bootinfo, because I can not access the machine physically. That is only possible in a month. So I guess I will wait with further actions until then.

Comment: I might suggest keeping /home on SSD, but have all the data folders then in your RAID. But RAID is for up time reliability not backup.  If no data in /home it becomes tiny, as it only has the users settings in hidden files & folders.

Comment: That might also be a possibility. I will check it out. I'm aware that RAID is for reliability and not backup though. I will need to think about a backup solution.